# Simple Google Maps v3 Marker not displaying on right location

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to show a marker on this [this location](https://www.google.com/maps/place/33%C2%B043'58.4%22N+73%C2%B005'30.0%22E/@33.7328889,73.0916667,19z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x0) (Islamabad, Pakistan) and has the co-ordinates `33.732877, 73.091717`

And this is the simple code from Google Examples. But this shows marker in different countries :( I tried reversing `Lat` `Lon` too

```
<style>
            html, body, #map-canvas {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px
            }
        </style>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>
        <script>
            function initialize() {
                var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.7332739, 73.0911567);
                var mapOptions = {
                    zoom: 4,
                    center: myLatlng
                }
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatlng,
                    map: map,
                    title: 'Hello World!'
                });
            }

            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    </body>
```

And its strange why it is not pointing to the location.

Comment: -33.7332739 seems wrong to me it should be positive: 33.7332739

Comment: @Blauharley tired that too ... did not work

Comment: have a try [here](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/4mtyu/) when keying in 33.7328889,73.0916667 with a marker it places a marker on your desired location.

Comment: @Blauharley it seems okay there but not on my side

Comment: when using your code with this location 33.7328889,73.0916667 a marker is placed on the right position. may be you have something old in browser cache?

Comment: @Dr.Molle its on my localhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to replace your code:

> var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.7332739, 73.0911567);

with this:

> var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(33.732889, 73.091667);

this demo: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/an_art/303bzjye/)

```
   function initialize() {
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(33.732889, 73.091667);
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 20,
                center: myLatlng
            }
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                title: 'Hello World!'
            });
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [this is](http://jsfiddle.net/eej35ye3/) what you want, right?

you need `new google.maps.LatLng(33.732877, 73.091717);` instead of `-33.7332739, 73.0911567`.

The geographic coordinate system in Google Maps works as follow:
Latitude and Longitude are represented as a float number, which is a degree.
While north and east are positive, south ans west is represented as negative numbers.

From your given code, as @Blauharley mentioned, you have a negative number for latitude, which indicates the position is located at a southern part of the earth, while your desire location locate at northern.

Also, the longitude you inputted is different from your companies' longitude. Even it is only 0.0005603 in difference, it is 53m apart from each other.

Hope this help :)

Comment: does not work :( if you run my code on your side does that works? does marker show in Islamabad, Pakistan?

Comment: umm.. I am seeing [this](http://postimg.org/image/3udx7jkpl/), it is Islamabad, Pakistan to me